# How to check whether network connection to port is not open, or nothing is listening at that port?

Tags: networking, telnet

I always check network connectivity using telnet [IP] [port]. However, sometimes the connection timeouts because nothing is listening to that port but the tunnel to that port is open. How do I check the difference, i.e. does telnet timeout because tunnel is not open or because nothing is listening to that port at the other end?

Comment: Can we assume there is no firewall on the network or on the target

Comment: The network opening should be done on the firewall, so yes there is a firewall

Comment: Connection timeouts do not mean nothing is listening. That causes 'connection refused'.

Answer (score 0):

Probably by using tcptraceroute, from the man page

> ```
>    This program attempts to trace the route an IP packet would  follow  to
>    some internet host by launching probe packets with a small ttl (time to
>    live) then listening for an ICMP "time exceeded" reply from a  gateway.
>    We  start our probes with a ttl of one and increase by one until we get
>    an ICMP "port unreachable" (or TCP reset)
> ```

set the max_ttl value to be appropriate for your firewall